# Displaying Doctrine object in twig

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I keep getting the error

```
Method "id" for object "AppBundle\Entity\Domains" does not exist in main\dashboard.html.twig at line 15
```

Here is the code

main\dashboard.html.twig

```
                    {% for domain in domains %}
                    <p> {{ domain.id }}</p>
                    <p> {{ domain.domain }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Appbundle\Entity\Domains.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Domains
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="domains")
 */
class Domains
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

     /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
     */
    protected $domain;

}
```

DashboardController.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\Domains;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $domain = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Domains');

    $domains = $domain->findAll();
    foreach ($domains as $domain) {
        dump($domain);
    }

    dump($domains);

    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render('main/dashboard.html.twig', array('domains' => $domains));
}

}
```

Now what I know is $domains is definitely getting the entries. E.g

```
Array ( [0] => AppBundle\Entity\Domains Object ( [id:protected] => 1 [domain:protected] => hello.com ) [1] => AppBundle\Entity\Domains Object ( [id:protected] => 2 [domain:protected] => stackoverflow.com ) )
```

And that Twig is definitely receiving 'domains', as when I put false variables into Twig it tells it can't find it. If I remove domain.id, then it will error out on domain.domain.

I've tried using both debug and dump within Twig to see the way 'domains' is formatted but I can't seem to get either to work within Symfony.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I think it must be either the way I pass $domains to Twig, or the way I'm trying to access domains within Twig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate getters/setters, like described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters

Comment: Thank you! It was getters/setters. I saw your post right before your edit and checked if it works with protected variables, it does